# Angular UIRouter $state.go inside onEnter not passing params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass $stateparams from a url to a non-child state and I'm coming up blank. The redirect is working just fine and the console.log that I threw in there is giving me what I would expect, but I'm not finding a way to get the params in the other controller. This is what I have in the state controller:

```
  .state('vip', {
    url: '/vip/:name',
    onEnter: ["$state", "$stateParams", function($state, $stateParams) {
      $state.go('leasee.two', {name: $stateParams.name} , {inherit: true});
      console.log("name: " + $stateParams.name);
    }]
  });
```

What should I be accessing in the other controller?

Comment: Can you show the definition of leasee.two?  You need to define name as a  param in leasee.two

Comment: You have typo: `{inhert: true});`, should be `{inherit: true});`

Comment: Would I just add "param: name,"? Thank you for catching the typo!